# Mathematica built-in function that translates number strings to numbers

Tags: built-in-symbols

I recently ran across a function in mathematica that translates "twenty-two" to 22, but I can not remember what it is and my searching through the help functions has yielded nothing. Can anybody help?

Comment: `Interpreter["SemanticNumber"]["seventy-five"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Interpreter["SemanticNumber"]["twenty-two"]
```